# how to send transaction with web3.py

Tags: go-ethereum, web3js, contract-development, web3.py, raw-transaction

I'm trying to use web3.py with infura.io to interact with my smartcontract. here is my simple greeter contract code

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.7;
contract greeter{
    string greeting;

    function greet(string memory _greeting)public {
        greeting=_greeting;
    }
    function getGreeting() public view returns(string memory) {
        return greeting;
    }
}
```

I deployed it on ropsten testnet. with web3.py I can read greeting from chain. I wanted to add new greeting string  with `greet` function. but somehow I have no idea about signing transaction. could anyone help me in understanding how to sign transacion and adding greeting to the contract using web3.py?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In web3py you can use the method [buildTransaction](https://web3py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/contracts.html#web3.contract.ContractFunction.buildTransaction):

```
myContract.functions.myMethod(*args, **kwargs).buildTransaction(transaction)
```

In your example you can do as follows:

```
tx = greeter.functions.greet("newGreet").buildTransaction({'nonce': web3.eth.getTransactionCount('your accountaddress')}}
```

Then you can sign the transaction using:

```
signed_tx = web3.eth.account.signTransaction(tx, private_key='your privateKey')
```

and finally you can send the transaction signed using:

```
web3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: but it is showing an error "AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'buildTransaction'". what seems to be the problem @jaime ?

Comment: Can you show your code? what version of web3py do you have?

Comment: here is the link to my code at https://drive.google.com/open?id=1IJmA94uvpJ1s33uQHOEYj2qRl42rNAah please consider having look at it @jaime

Comment: Notice that you must use contract_instance.functions.greet("text").build... notice that versions before 4.0 do not have this functionality. let me know

Comment: It should be `build_transaction`, not `buildTransaction`.